# Find first digit of 2^n where n is of order 10^5

Tags: algorithm

Today while going through a random video on youtube, I learn't about a very interesting law called [Benford's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law). I was wondering if it is possible to write a code to verify it for a^n.

I want to write a code that prints the first digit of 2^n where n is of order 10^5. Is it possible to write a code for it?

I know I haven't posted any code sample or shown any research effort.I am unable to think of any algorithm for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use logarithms.

```
log_10(2) = 0.30102999566

log_10(2^100000) = 30102.999566
```

In other words, 2^100000 is a 30103-digit number, whose first digit can be found from the fractional part of this number:

```
10^0.999566 = 9.9900..
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That really helps.

Comment: The method is absolutely correct, but here is an issue with the precision when working with computer programs `log_10 (2^3)=0.903089987`  `10^0.903089987 = 7.999999998` so program takes it as 7 and not 8. Maybe in the above case also it is 1 and not 9?

Comment: @ARBY Yes that's true, although 3 isn't really of the order of 10^5. The result for 2^100000 is definitely correct.

Comment: Agreed. For higher powers, probability of such cases will be fairly low, so in most cases this will be correct. Thanks again.